# VHDL - rand*real(2**32-1) : can this cause an overflow issue?

Tags: vhdl, testbench

I'm studying VHDL implementations of multipliers: I found [this one](https://opencores.org/projects/mult_booth_array) and i'm trying to modify it. Default word size is 8 bit and the design is working (both simulation and synthesis) for any size up to 30 bits. I want to set it to 32 and simulate in Vivado 2018.3.
Here's the test bench:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.math_real.all;

entity tb_mult_booth_array is
  generic(
  word_size_a   : integer := 32;
  word_size_b   : integer := 32;
  use_pipelining : boolean := true
);
end tb_mult_booth_array;

architecture tb_arch of tb_mult_booth_array is

  constant no_of_rows : integer := integer(floor(real(word_size_b+2)/2.0));

  signal clk : std_logic := '1';
  signal rst : std_logic;

  signal a : std_logic_vector(word_size_a-1 downto 0);
  signal b : std_logic_vector(word_size_b-1 downto 0);
  signal p_dut,p_ref,p_refd : std_logic_vector(word_size_a+word_size_b-1 downto 0);

begin

  clk <= not clk after 5 ns;
  rst <= '1', '0' after 10 ns;

mult_booth_array_inst : entity work.mult_booth_array
  generic map (
    word_size_a   => word_size_a,
    word_size_b   => word_size_b,
    use_pipelining => use_pipelining
  )
  port map (
    clk_i => clk,
    rst_i => rst,
    ce_i  => '1',
    a_i   => a,
    b_i   => b,
    p_o   => p_dut
  );


  process
    variable seed1, seed2: positive;
    variable rand : real;
  begin
    a <= (others => '0');
    b <= (others => '0');

    -- Random Stimuli Generation
    loop
      uniform(seed1, seed2, rand);
      wait until clk'event and clk='0';
      a <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(integer(trunc(rand*real(2**word_size_a-1))),word_size_a));
     uniform(seed1, seed2, rand);
     b <=    std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(integer(trunc(rand*real(2**word_size_b-1))),word_size_b));
     p_ref <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(a) * unsigned(b));
    end loop;
 end process;

delay_ref: if use_pipelining generate
    ref_delay : entity work.register_chain
  generic map(
    word_size => word_size_a+word_size_b,
    delay => no_of_rows-1
  )
  port map(
    clk_i => clk,
    rst_i => rst,
    ce_i => '1',
    d_i => p_ref,
    q_o => p_refd
  );
end generate;

forward_ref: if not use_pipelining generate
    p_refd <= p_ref;
end generate;

process
variable seed1, seed2: positive;
variable rand : real;
begin
    wait until rst'event and rst='0';
    for i in 0 to no_of_rows-1 loop
       wait until clk'event and clk='0';
    end loop;
loop
    wait until clk'event and clk='0';
    assert (p_dut = p_refd) report "Test failure" severity warning;
end loop;
end process;

end architecture;
```

The simulation is halted at 1st clk negedge, with the error msg:

> ERROR: [Simulator 45-1] A fatal run-time error was detected.  Simulation cannot continue.

Vivado points to this line:

```
a <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(integer(trunc(rand*real(2**word_size_a-1))),word_size_a));
```

I was not able to find other infos in the logs. In the [paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7203791) referenced in the opencores page they test operands up to 64 bits so I guess this should work.

Any hints?

Comment: Did it work with 8 bit wordsize?

Comment: All processes have a `wait until` statement so no sensitivity list is needed. And yes, with 8bit I was able to simulate a synthesize.

Comment: I think Vivado might be one of the simulators that limits intermediate calculations to 32 bits for integers. maybe try (rand)*(2.0**real(word_size_a)-1)

Comment: 2**32 (4294967296) isn't a value of the minimum range of type integer. See IEEE Std 1076-2008 5.2.3.2 Predefined integer types, "range –2147483647 to +2147483647",  5.2.3.1 "The same arithmetic operators are predefined for all integer types (see 9.2). It is an error if the execution of such an operation (in particular, an implicit conversion) cannot deliver the correct result (that is, if the value corresponding to the mathematical result is not a value of the integer type)." You'd need bigger integers to not have an error.

Comment: @user8352 So the problem here should be the cast from real to integer right? How do I use bigger integers?
@ks0ze unfortunately what you suggest gives the following `ERROR: [VRFC 10-724] found '0' definitions of operator "-", cannot determine exact overloaded matching definition for "-"` Maybe i should use another lib?

Comment: There's a catch-22 stopping declaration of a larger integer type 9.4 Universal expression "For the evaluation of an operation of a universal expression, the following rules apply. If the result is of type universal_integer, then the values of the operands and the result shall lie within the range of the integer type with the widest range provided by the implementation, excluding type universal_integer itself." Consider Jim Lewis' OSVVM, [Randomization Using Randompkg](https://github.com/OSVVM/OSVVM/blob/master/doc/RandomPkg_user_guide.pdf) section 6 Large Vector Randomization. Read the source.

Comment: @a_bet maybe 1.0?

Comment: 15.5 Abstract literals, 15.5.1 General "There are two classes of abstract literals: real literals and integer literals. A real literal is an abstract literal that includes a point; an integer literal is an abstract literal without a point. Real literals are the literals of the type universal_real. Integer literals are the literals of the type universal_integer."

Comment: Reading through math_real procedure uniform and the OSVVM source is insightful. Because of the seed values you can't get more than 30 bits out of math_real.uniform (they're limited to less than positive'high). OSVVM gets's larger unsigned vectors 30 bits at a time with an impure function Unsigned. Which when the RandomParm Distribution type is set to UNIFORM provides the same l'Ecuyer distirbution as the math_real uniform procedure. Here, get upto 30 bits at a time.